# my pictures are out of the div

Tags: html

I have a problem, I have a div and it's background color is black. I put two pictures in the div but when I see them they are in list orders, I said ok and I wanted to be in the div but side by side, and so i did "float: left;" but now they are completely out of div!!!! Please help!!!!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

div.images {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}

#styles { 
        margin: auto;
        background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 60%
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="styles">
<h1>First heading.</h1>
<p>Check check</p>
 <hr>
 <p>Some pictures</p><br>
 <div class="images">
      <img src="Nabeel1.jpg" width="200" height="200">
   <div class="desc">Tom Clancy's</div>
 </div>
 <br>
  <div class="images">
      <img src="usama.jpg" width="200" height="200">
   <div class="desc">Tom Clancy's</div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating image bleeds out of its div container into another div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381405/floating-image-bleeds-out-of-its-div-container-into-another-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need element with clear:both; at the end of floating elements sequence.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

div.images {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#styles { 
        margin: auto;
        background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 60%
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="styles">
<h1>First heading.</h1>
<p>Check check</p>
 <hr>
 <p>Some pictures</p><br>
 <div class="images">
      <img src="Nabeel1.jpg" width="200" height="200">
   <div class="desc">Tom Clancy's</div>
 </div>
 <div class="images">
      <img src="usama.jpg" width="200" height="200">
   <div class="desc">Tom Clancy's</div>
 </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.images {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 60%
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>First heading.</h1>
  <p>Check check</p>
  <hr>
  <p>Some pictures</p>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="img.jpg" width="200" height="200">
    <div class="desc">Tom Clancy's</div>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="img.jpg" width="200" height="200">
    <div class="desc">Tom Clancy's</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No element should be allowed on either the left or the right side of the floating `div`

Read more about [clear at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

div.images {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#styles { 
        margin: auto;
        background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 60%
}
.clear{
        clear: both;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="styles">
<h1>First heading.</h1>
<p>Check check</p>
 <hr>
 <p>Some pictures</p><br>
 <div class="images">
      <img src="Nabeel1.jpg" width="200" height="200">
   <div class="desc">Tom Clancy's</div>
 </div>
 <br>
  <div class="images">
      <img src="usama.jpg" width="200" height="200">
   <div class="desc">Tom Clancy's</div>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</body>
```